# How to get the domain name in nodejs

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have nginx in front which give proxy pass to node server.
How do I get the domain name which nginx pass to node.

I tried req.headers.host which gives IP address instead of domain name.

e.g. if current url is "http://xyz.abc.com/" then I want http://xyz.abc.com/ but I get ip like 127.0.0.1

How do I get domain name??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the correct host header from nginx to your Node.js app via the $host variable. You'll need something like this in your nginx.conf file under the server/location section:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3002$request_uri;
    proxy_redirect off;
    break;
  }
```

Comment: `break` is useless here.